# Structure for a series of data with inner groups

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a series of price and time objects, the base time frame is at 1 minute intervals. I want to be able to access this data other time frames as well. I'm not sure on the best structure but I'm thinking of the Bar class shown below. The disadvantage I see is that as the base time frame is smaller than the other time frames there will be a large amount of duplicate data as the larger time frames are the sum of the smaller time frame. Is there a better data structure to use?

I will also want to be able to quickly process the data, I need to be able to calculate averages etc from the series. From the base time frame this is easy as i can just sum the next x items in series. This however wont work for the Larger time frame properties.

```
public class Bar
{
    public TimeFrame TimeFrame { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public double Open { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Close { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get { return Date.Add(Time); }
    }

    public Bar FiveMinute { get; set; }
    public Bar FifteenMinute { get; set; }
    public Bar ThirtyMinute { get; set; }
    public Bar Hour { get; set; }
    public Bar FourHour { get; set; }
    public Bar Daily { get; set; }
    public Bar Weekly { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of your source data? Where do the source data reside? How do you access them (linq to sql/entities?). To me it seems you should stick to the elementary data and aggregate them on request by grouping time intervals.

Comment: Source data is just a DB table of a 1 Minute bar (Date, Time, Open, High, Low) I'l have a go at grouping on request